# Jenkins Conditional Behavior

Tags: jenkins

I have a project that sometimes doesn't link correctly if you try to rebuild it after making updates. After doing a clean build, it works fine. I'd like to replicate this behavior in Jenkins - first try rebuilding, then if that fails, run the clean script and try again, and only if that fails, fail the build.

How do I build in conditionals like this?

Comment: Please elaborate some more. Who calls into the build system and where?

Comment: It's just a standard msbuild process on a sln. If the build fails, you clean all, then build again, and it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can use a simple try/catch block in your pipeline script:](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#flow-control)

```
try {
    // build step without clean
}
catch (error) {
    // clean step
    // build step
}
```

(but you might want to consider cleaning before every build and/or figuring out why it's failing)

Comment: Thanks! Works great.